# array to data react native toFixed is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, charts

I work with the react-native-chart-kit and I want to make it dynamic. So I´ve made a state that looks like this:

```
Array [
  2,
  1,
]
```

In the example of there code it looks like this:

```
    const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [ 20, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43 ]
  }]
}
```

And this is my code:

```
    <LineChart
                    data={{
                        labels: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za', 'Zo'],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [this.state.counter]
                        }]
                    }}
```

The error is:

> TypeError: TypeError: data[0].toFixed is not a function. (In
>   'data[0].toFixed(decimalPlaces)', 'data[0].toFixed' is undefined)

UPDATE:

This is how I make my state:
First in an foreach I push each value to an array after that I set my state with that array.

```
const total = [];

total.push(Object.values(childSnapshot.val()).length);

this.setState({
   counter: total
});
```

My state looks like this:

```
counter: []
```

This is my output from the console log:

```
Array [
  2,
  1,
]
```

Comment: Can you also show the lines that setup the state. It looks like `this.state.counter` is not a number

Comment: I was guessing the same, but don't know how to make it a number because the console.log gives it back as a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you wrapped this.state.counter in an array but it's already an array. Try the below.

```
data={{
    labels: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za', 'Zo'],
    datasets: [{
        data: this.state.counter
    }]
}}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but this also gives an error. So now I I've installed an other package called react-native-pure-chart and this works perfectly fine.